# cannot read simple txt file in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner. I have a simple txt file which I need to read (using numpy). I have the program in the same directory as the .txt file.

I have checked the cwd and it's the right one. Also, I've written a text file in order to see if python wants to open that one - that file opens just fine.

```
import os
import numpy as np

np.loadtxt("test2.txt")
```

The code above gives me the error.

The code below works just fine.

```
import os
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
np.savetxt("test.txt", x)
y = np.loadtxt("test.txt")
print(y)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\detest\admi.py", line 5, in <module>
    np.loadtxt("test2.txt")
  File "C:\Users\Mircea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 962, in loadtxt
    fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\Mircea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 266, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
  File "C:\Users\Mircea\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 624, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: test2.txt not found.
```

Comment: ``OSError: test2.txt not found.`` did you have a file named "test2.txt" in the same folder than your python file ?

Comment: yes, both test.txt and test2.txt are in the same folder (where there's also the python file)

Comment: Could it be because you are using the script in a different drive that causes this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i have just moved the folder to the same drive where the python installation is, but the error i get is the same :(

Comment: How do you execute your script? Do you use an IDE or the command line?

Comment: IDE (i believe). I've installed python 3.7.4 (under Windows) just before writing the code, then i've added numpy (pip install numpy - gave me a writing error, so that i need to use --user, tried that and it worked). I ran IDLE (python 3.7 64 bit) and a shell opened. File - new file and wrote the code there

Comment: Late Edit - tried to run the code from cmd, same error

Comment: Make sure you're in the right place and the file is there: print `os.getcwd()` and `os.listdir()` in the script.

Comment: Flagging to close as typo since [OP said there turned out to be a trailing space in the filename.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097492/cannot-read-simple-txt-file-in-python#comment100718191_57097838) @Mircea Glad you got it sorted at least! :p

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the Python read file instead?

```
path = ''                  # location of your file
openfile = open(path, 'r') # open file
openfile.read()            # return all content of file
openfile.close()           # close file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - yes, I've tried it myself in the meantime, the issue is the same - it works with the file I've generated but not with the file I actually want to work with...

Comment: Are you using a windows system? If so keep in mind a data.txt file will be data.txt.txt because it hides extensions.

Comment: It's windows but both the text file names are the same except 1 character (test.txt and test2.txt). Both files and the .py file are in the same folder

Comment: Either you're mistaken about what the current directory is, or you're mistaken about the exact filenames that are in the directory.  Add these lines to your script: `print(os.getcwd())` and `print(os.listdir())`.

Comment: Go into your explorer and find the file. Copy the path directory to the file and plug it into the code above. It does not have to be in the same folder as your py file you just need to give Python the directory to where it is

Comment: When entering an absolute path on Windows, please make sure you use a raw string (`r"C:\path\to\file.txt"`) or escape the backslashes (`"C:\\path\\to\\file.txt"`)

Comment: Thanks all for the answers and thanks Jonh Gordon especially for the idea - the guy who created the file I wanted to work with added a space after the file name and I could not see that in windows. The listdir command worked, showed me the added space. The problem is solved. I feel like an idiot now.